# Class ByteArrayDataSource in Java 1.4

Tags: java, itext, jakarta-mail, java1.4

I need to use this class ByteArrayDataSource to send an email with an attachment in it (a pdf created with iText) but our environment is running on java 1.4 but this class is in Javamail requires higher version.

I have to use this class as below:

```
//now write the PDF content to the output stream   
    outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pdfCreator.createPdf(data,outputStream);
    byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();


    //construct the pdf body part
    DataSource dataSource = **new ByteArrayDataSource**(bytes, "application/pdf");
    MimeBodyPart pdfBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    pdfBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
    pdfBodyPart.setFileName("listadosCitaciones.pdf");

    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement an equivalent class yourself from scratch.  Look at the javadocs for the methods in the `DataSource` interface, and it should be obvious how you need to implement them.

(I'd do it for you, but I've written enough boring code for this week :-) )

Comment: It worked! I found the source code on a pair of webs, so I only had to Copy&Paste it... I had to implement a pair of class, but luckily didn't had more dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen is right, you just need to implement a custom datasource like this:

```
public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] b, String ct) {
        bytes = b;
        contentType = ct;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private byte[] bytes;
    private String contentType;
}
```

and then you canuse it the same way the jdk1.5 ByteArrayDataSource.